# R Shiny Refresh global variable if needed

Tags: r, shiny, refresh

I have a user that inputs into a database,  what they want for sidebar Menu options for their R Shiny page. When the user hits Refresh, F5 on the browser or shutdowns and restarts the browser, the user still doesn't see what they just added to the database. I don't want this to run every time so was trying to add a button or only when update timestamp in database changes. I just can't figure out how to get the global variables to update from the server section of the code.  Example snippet of the code below:

```
query = paste0("select * from database.animals")
rs = dbSendQuery(conn, query)
result = fetch(rs,-1)
dbDisconnect(conn)

type<-distinct(result,type)
breed<-distinct(result,breed)
gender<-distinct(result,gender)
age<-distinct(result,age)

ui <- dashboardPage(

   dashboardSidebar(
     sidebarMenu(
          selectInput("type","Type",choices=c(type),multiple=FALSE),
          selectInput("breed","Breed:", choices=c(breed), multiple=TRUE),
          selectInput("gender","Gender:", choices=c(gender), multiple=TRUE),
          selectInput("age","Age:", choices=c(age), multiple=TRUE)
     )
   )
 )
server <- fuction(input, output, session) {

   ...What do I add in here to rerun that SQL and update the global 
      variables only when needed?.....

}
```

Comment: You can generate your UI inputs from within the `server` function using [`renderUI`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html). So when the data changes, the server will auto-refresh the UI inputs.

Comment: So move all of the code above UI section and put in UI section?

Comment: essentially yes. You put the `selectInput()` code inside an `output$myOutputId <- renderUI({ selectInput() })` function in the `server`. Then in the `ui` you have `uiOutput('myOutputId')`

Comment: The section 'Creating Controls On the Fly With renderUI` in that article I linked has an example. And [here is](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/renderUI.html) the function definition and example

Comment: Not quite getting the results I want, is there a way to have it when this report is loaded for the first time uses the code I show, but then add like ReactivePoll in the Server section to only update the menu if database update timestamp was changed since the loading of the report?